# In Android Studio since Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() may be removed soon how to create folder in root directory

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-storage

After **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** in Android Studio is deprecated , How can i cteate a folder or file in root directory of sdcard like where folders like WhatsApp , Android , Downloads , etc are present in Android

[Here i want to create a file or folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlOUm.jpg)

Comment: Request 'all files access` or use SAF on an Android 11+ device. For all other devices continue using it.

Comment: Okay thanks i was confused